# Translate dataframe into XML

Tags: xml, r, dataframe

I have a dataframe df that looks like this :

```
    CODE     GROUP      SET 
1   100      6000       20
2   100      7000       30
3   200      8000       40
```

How can I pipe separate and wrap the data frame rows according to the example below ?

```
<rows>
<row>100|6000|20</row>
<row>100|7000|30</row>
<row>200|8000|40</row>
<rows>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not fancy, but:

```
sprintf("<rows>\n%s\n</rows>\n", paste(apply(dat, 1, function(x) {
  paste("<row>", paste(x, collapse="|"), "</row>", sep="")
}), collapse="\n"))
## [1] "<rows>\n<row>100|6000|20</row>\n<row>100|7000|30</row>\n<row>200|8000|40</row></rows>\n"
```

Use `writeLines` to save it to a file and you'll see:

```
<rows>
<row>100|6000|20</row>
<row>100|7000|30</row>
<row>200|8000|40</row>
</rows>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `xmlOutputDOM`function. It creates an object with various methods to create XML:

```
myDF <- read.table(text = "    CODE     GROUP      SET 
1   100      6000       20
2   100      7000       30
3   200      8000       40", header = TRUE)

library(XML)
con <- xmlOutputDOM(tag="rows")
apply(myDF, 1, function(x){
  con$addTag("row", paste(x, collapse = "|"))
})


> (myXML <- con$value())
<rows>
  <row>100|6000|20</row>
  <row>100|7000|30</row>
  <row>200|8000|40</row>
</rows>
```

To output the created XML as a character you can use `saveXML`:

```
> cat(saveXML(myXML))
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rows>
 <row>100|6000|20</row>
 <row>100|7000|30</row>
 <row>200|8000|40</row>
</rows>
```

Comment: The source for `xmlOutputDOM` is fantastic.  Many useful functions just in the source code

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xmlNode` from package `XML`

```
library(XML)
vals <- do.call(paste, c(myDF, sep = "|"))
node <- xmlNode("rows", .children = lapply(vals, xmlNode, name = "row"))
```

This produces the following XML node

```
<rows>
 <row>100|6000|20</row>
 <row>100|7000|30</row>
 <row>200|8000|40</row>
</rows>

class(node)
# [1] "XMLNode"          "RXMLAbstractNode" "XMLAbstractNode"
```

where `myDF` is the data from @jdharrison's  answer.